# tableview's uitableviewcell display in worng order and duplicate rows

Tags: uitableview

This is a chat app, I'm using tableview to display the chatting data between user and others, however I'v got Rows are displayed multiple(duplicate). The code is below:

```
#define kMyTag 1

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
    NSDictionary *messageDic = [self.chatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([[messageDic objectForKey:@"myself"]boolValue] == false) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MessageChatFriendCell"; 
        MessageChatFriendCell *cell = (MessageChatFriendCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[MessageChatFriendCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        NSDictionary *chatInfo = [self.chatArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        UIView *chatView = [chatInfo objectForKey:@"view"];
        chatView.tag = kMyTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:chatView];
        return cell;
    } else  {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MessageChatSelfCell";
        MessageChatSelfCell *cell = (MessageChatSelfCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[MessageChatSelfCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        NSDictionary *chatInfo = [self.chatArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        UIView *chatView = [chatInfo objectForKey:@"view"];
        chatView.tag = kMyTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:chatView];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

the print results for each row are:

```
2012-08-02 15:44:47.152  MessageChatSelfCell-><UIView: 0x222790; frame = (85 0; 230 114); tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x222320>>
2012-08-02 15:44:47.166  MessageChatFriendCell-><UIView: 0x21d790; frame = (0 0; 210 132); tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x21d5c0>>
2012-08-02 15:44:47.176  MessageChatFriendCell-><UIView: 0x21bde0; frame = (0 0; 177 60); tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x21be10>>
2012-08-02 15:44:47.183  MessageChatSelfCell-><UIView: 0x216430; frame = (85 0; 230 168); tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x215fc0>>
2012-08-02 15:44:59.232  MessageChatFriendCell-><UIView: 0x215150; frame = (0 0; 86 60); tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x214eb0>>
2012-08-02 15:45:00.465  MessageChatSelfCell-><UIView: 0x213220; frame = (85 0; 230 78); tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x213250>>
```

Please advise, thanks!

Updated 2012-08-08

```
#define WRITER_NAME_LABEL_TAG 4
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
    static NSString *MessageChatSelfCellIdentifier = @"MessageChatSelfCell";    
    static NSString *MessageChatFriendCellIdentifier = @"MessageChatFriendCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    UIView *chatView = nil;
    NSDictionary *messageDic = [self.chatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *text = [messageDic objectForKey:@"compiled"];
    BOOL myMessage = [[messageDic objectForKey:@"myself"] boolValue];

    if (myMessage) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MessageChatSelfCellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil) 
        { 
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                           reuseIdentifier:MessageChatSelfCellIdentifier];

        chatView = [self bubbleView:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", text] 
                                       from:YES];
        chatView.tag = WRITER_NAME_LABEL_TAG;
        NSLog(@"MessageChatFriendCell->%@",chatView);
        [cell addSubview:chatView];
        }else {
            chatView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:WRITER_NAME_LABEL_TAG];
        }
    } else  {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MessageChatFriendCellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil) 
        { 
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                          reuseIdentifier:MessageChatFriendCellIdentifier];

        NSString *text = [messageDic objectForKey:@"compiled"];        
        UIView *chatView = [self bubbleView:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", text] 
                                       from:NO];
        chatView.tag = WRITER_NAME_LABEL_TAG;
                NSLog(@"MessageChatSelfCell->%@",chatView);
        [cell addSubview:chatView];
        }else {
            chatView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:WRITER_NAME_LABEL_TAG];
        }
    }  
        return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered your another question [How to calculate the Width and Height of NSString on UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002314/how-to-calculate-the-width-and-height-of-nsstring-on-uilabel)

They are similar problem. the code below I C&P from the other question.

That's because you did not reuse the table cell, the structure should be like:

```
NSString *text = [messageInfo objectForKey:@"compiled"];
if(cell == nil) 
        { 
     writerNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
     writerNameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
     writerNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     [cell addSubview:writerNameLabel];
}
else {
     writerNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:WRITER_NAME_LABEL_TAG];
}
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(296,9999);
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] 
               constrainedToSize:constraint 
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[writerNameLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(writerNameLabel.frame.origin.x, writerNameLabel.frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height)];
```

I've been gone through and answered some of your question, that's correct way to write your tableview controller. And your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Few things u should change,  first don't store your views in chatInfo instead store your data.
Next add the view to the cell only when u create new cell, otherwise u will add more then one view to a reused cell.
Take a look at the example below, here I'm creating a cell with the message writer name, for my messages the writer name will be in the right hand side, and for my friend messages it will be on the left.
Pay attention that I'm only add the writer name label when I create a new cell, then I give it a tag so I can get the label next time I want to change it.

```
#define WRITER_NAME_LABEL_TAG 1

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MessageChatFriendCellIdentifier = @"MessageChatFriendCell";
    static NSString *MessageChatSelfCellIdentifier = @"MessageChatSelfCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    UILabel *writerNameLabel = nil;

    NSDictionary *messageInfo = [self.chatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    BOOL myMessage = [[messageInfo objectForKey:@"myself"] boolValue];

    if (myMessage) {        
        // this is my message
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MessageChatSelfCellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil) 
        { 
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                           reuseIdentifier:MessageChatSelfCellIdentifier] autorelease];

            writerNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)];
            writerNameLabel.tag = WRITER_NAME_LABEL_TAG;
            writerNameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            [cell addSubview:writerNameLabel];
        }
        else {
            writerNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:WRITER_NAME_LABEL_TAG];
        }
    }
    else {
        // this is my friend message
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MessageChatFriendCellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil) 
        { 
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                           reuseIdentifier:MessageChatFriendCellIdentifier] autorelease];

            writerNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)];
            writerNameLabel.tag = WRITER_NAME_LABEL_TAG;
            writerNameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            [cell addSubview:writerNameLabel];
        }
        else {
            writerNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:WRITER_NAME_LABEL_TAG];
        }
    }

    // get the current writer name from the model
    NSString *writerName = [messageInfo objectForKey:@"writer"];        

    // configure cell...
    writerNameLabel.text = writerName;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the reason I'm using UIView is that I have to add the user Image and the message bubble image into the UIView to display.

Comment: It still the same technique, just add a UIView before the writerLabel, give it a tag and add the writer label to it as a subview. But usually when dealing with complex custom views it just better/easier to subclass the UITableViewCell.

Comment: I modified the function, but the cell still mixed up, please have a look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look at what I have done, I didn't set the writerName inside the if(cell==nil) statement - this is only for creating the views. I did it in the end of the method where it say "// configure cell..." This is where you need to set your text in the view.