# How to calculate the Width and Height of NSString on UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I am working on a project to make the NSString on UILabel Width and Height dynamically.
I tried with:

```
NSString *text = [messageInfo objectForKey:@"compiled"];
writerNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
writerNameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
writerNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(296,9999);
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] 
               constrainedToSize:constraint 
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
NSLog(@"sizewidth = %f, sizeheight = %f", size.width, size.height);
NSLog(@"writerNameLabel.frame.size.width 1 -> %f",writerNameLabel.frame.size.width);
[writerNameLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(writerNameLabel.frame.origin.x, writerNameLabel.frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height)];

CGRect labelFram = writerNameLabel.frame;
labelFram.origin.x = cell.frame.size.width - writerNameLabel.frame.size.width - 80;
writerNameLabel.frame = labelFram;
NSLog(@"writerNameLabel.frame.size.width 2-> %f",writerNameLabel.frame.size.width);
```

[image]

Please see the green bubble not the grey one.
Still not right.

The code for bubble

```
bubbleImageView.frame = CGRectMake(writerNameLabel.frame.origin.x, writerNameLabel.frame.origin.y, writerNameLabel.frame.size.width+15, writerNameLabel.frame.size.height+5);
```

Please Advise! Thanks!

Comment: This question has been handled before, This post will be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965809/how-to-use-nsstrings-sizewithfont-and-drawinrect-to-workout-how-much-of-a-strin

Comment: @JeroenMoons: Thanks for the link, however, It doesn't help, and in the second image, the contents of two greem bubbles are same (text is test), but the display result are different.

Comment: OK :) What is the initial size of the writerNameLabel? You get two results per approach, how are these obtained?

Comment: @JeroenMoons I just updated my question to add the initial size of the writerNameLabel, please have a look, thanks.

Comment: It seems that you set the frame size more than once in your code, why is that exactly? What happens if you comment out the last 3 lines of code?

Comment: @JeroenMoons：the initial value of origin.x is 0, and I'll make the green bubble on the right side as the iPhone message display view does, so the last 3 lines to calculate the correct origin.x of the UILabel should be.

Comment: At which point in your code are you NSLogging the writerNameLabel frame width? Also, how are the bubbles constructed exactly?

Comment: @JeroenMoons: Updated my question with the info you need. and I think we can ignore the initial value, because it will resized with the size of the NSSring laster anyway. Thanks

Comment: Ok I'll look into it. The initial size is relevant in the first case because you use it to constrain the output of the sizeWithFont:... function

Comment: about the NSLog results: the first line is what the sizeWithFont method gives you? And the second the value of writerNameLabel's frame at the end of your code excerpt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you did not reuse the table cell, the structure should be like:

```
NSString *text = [messageInfo objectForKey:@"compiled"];
if(cell == nil) 
        { 
     writerNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
     writerNameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
     writerNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     [cell addSubview:writerNameLabel];
}
else {
     writerNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:WRITER_NAME_LABEL_TAG];
}
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(296,9999);
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] 
               constrainedToSize:constraint 
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[writerNameLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(writerNameLabel.frame.origin.x, writerNameLabel.frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height)];
```

I've been gone through and answered some of your question, that's correct way to write your tableview controller. And your problem will be solved.

Comment: sizeWithFont is DEPRECATED from iOS 7, please use boundingRectWithSize instead